# python 3: Name error from input within a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

I need to define a function that multiplies two integers gathered from user input. Instructions say to gather user input "within the function", but doing so results in error:

```
NameError: name 'num_1' is not defined.
```

Here was my attempt:

```
def multiply(num_1, num_2):
    num_1 = input("enter a whole number:")
    num_2 = input("enter another whole number:")
    result = int(num_1)*int(num_2)
    return(num_1 + " * " + num_2 + " = " + str(result))

multiply(num_1, num_2)
```

Changing the code so that input is gathered when calling the function makes it pass:

```
def multiply(num_1, num_2):
    result = int(num_1)*int(num_2) 
    return(num_1 + " * " + num_2 + " = " + str(result))

print(multiply(input("enter  a whole number: "), input("enter another whole number: ")))
```

But I want to know if it's POSSIBLE to gather input within the function as the directions stated.

Comment: Sure, *just remove the function arguments*. Your function doesn't take arguments, as it takes the values from `input()` calls *instead*.

Comment: So `def multiply():`, and then call with `multiply()`.

Comment: I wish the people who are downvoting the answers would leave comments saying why.

Comment: @Chandra see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Since the input is defined by the user, the function has no input arguments. Use:

```
def multiply():
    num_1 = input("enter a whole number:")
    num_2 = input("enter another whole number:")
    result = int(num_1)*int(num_2) 
    return(str(num_1) + " * " + str(num_2) + " = " + str(result))

multiply()
```

**Results**:

```
'1 * 2 = 2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are gathering values inside the function, there is no need to pass them as arguments.

```
def multiply_two_numbers():
    x = input("Enter a number: ")
    y = input("Enter another number: ")
    return x*y

>>> multiply_two_numbers()
Enter a number: 10
Enter another number: 12.5
125.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to obtain input from a function. You are getting the input from the user correctly, however, it looks like you're having a problem with function scoping.

The NameError problem you are getting is because of the scope of your variables. You have defined them in your function multiply and you are trying to access them outside of the scope of the function. Python function scope means that you only have access to these variables in the indented space below the function.

For example: if you had:

```py
multiply():
  num_1 = 2
  print(num1)
```

There would be no name error because you are within the scope of the function. However, if you had done something like this:

```py
multiply():
  num_1 = 2

print(num1)
```

You would receive NameError: num_1 is not defined